# "Read" a Bluetooth tracking device

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, win-universal-app, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to get a Bluetooth tracking device such as TrackR, Tile, Chipolo, ... and write my own app to detect my devices on a Windows 10 Mobile device. Are they encrypted in some way so that only their app can use them?

Can anyone point me in the right direction for doing that? Or tell me that it's impossible.

Comment: A very broad question - and every BT device will be different. You'll need to investigate the published API for the device you're interested in. And if it's not published, maybe someone has reverse-engineered it? But... this is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: `every BT device will be different` - Do you _know_ that? Maybe all are encrypted? Or maybe all are quite simple (though they might have different api's, they might be basically the same). Thank you for your input, but it seems that you don't know their api's. Maybe someone that does will come around and answer.

Comment: Sigh. Please don't assume what I know and don't know. Your question is off-topic. This isn't a programming question.

Comment: Detection is independent of encryption. If the device is undirectedly advertising, you can see it with every scanning BLE device that is inside the communication range. But if you can talk to the device and exchange information, that completely depends on the device you want to talk to. Typcially, devices expose services of which some may be used without encryption and some (most) will need encryption, but this is difficult to answer in a general way.

Comment: @Nebr Thanks. What do you mean "undirectedly" advertising?

Comment: Important question first: Do we talk about Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy? Since you tagged Bluetooth and Bluetooth Low Energy, I would normally assume the latter, but your question has me doubting, since advertising is only a feature of Low Energy and Classic users would not know it.

Comment: @Nebr Low Energy. The answer to your doubt is that I really don't know much about Bluetooth, and was wondering if there's any point in pursuing  this matter. In a way - _that_ is actually my question - how does Bluetooth LE work (from a developer's perspective) - is it like smart cards where you can't do anything without the API (unless you reverse engineer it) or not?

Comment: There are existing frameworks where you can develop applications without having to know how exactly pairing, advertising etc. works (like Android SDK, Xamarin etc.). In principle, one could also develop everything from scratch, but that is as recommandable as writing an own compiler.

Comment: To answer your question concerning undirected advertising: Advertising is used by a peripheral device to directly send a small amount of data to other devices (typically a short name of the device and some other custom information) for identification and information purposes. If it is targeted to a specific device (typically in order to allow quick connection), we speak of "directed advertising". If it is broadcasted to every listener, it is called "undirected advertising".

Comment: @Nebr Thank you for your detailed answers (I'd be happy to upvote them if you post them as an answer). It then looks like it _will be_ possible to identify my tags if they use indirect advertising, and not (unless I find their API's) if they directly advertise. Thanks!

Comment: Direct advertisement is reserved for establishing a connection. It is targeted to a specific device during the connection process, but it can in principle be seen by any device around (in fact, there is no possibility to send messages directly to a device without other devices around being able to get the message as well; thats why encryption is used for security). I would advice to read the details about this somewhere else, as a thorough explanation does not fit into the comments. I will add a bit information in my answer though.

Comment: @Nebr Everyone will be able to see the broadcast, but if the tag's ID is encrypted, only those with the appropriate key and knowledge of the API will be able to read the ID. Though if it's encrypted without a changing part ("salt" or something) - I _will_ be able to recognize my tags... I guess I'll just have to buy one and experiment. Though it would be nice if someone who knows about the specific tags will be able to tell me which ones I could use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detection is independent of encryption.

Let us call the main device with which other devices should be detected the "Central", and these other devices "Peripherals".

Every Peripheral that wishes to be detected has to send advertisements. There are several advertising modes; without going to much into detail, these different modes are for allowing the peripheral to be discovered, or to be connected with, or both.

All these advertisements are unencrypted, so any device can "see" and understand these advertisments. A Central just has to go into scanning mode; in this mode, the Central listenes for any advertisements it can detect. After finishing the scan, all found devices are presented in a list. There is no encryption here; encryption only comes into play after two devices have connected and at least one devices demands encrypted communication. But this is not necessary for finding and identifying devices.

Note that the only information you can get without connecting is the advertisement data (and possible some additional scan response data). Typically, a short device name or identifier is part of the advertisement data to allow for identification of the device type. If the device implements the Device Information Service, each information there can also be read without encryption (but you have to connect and discover this service first). Most devices will want the Central to know their name, type and purpose, so typically that information will not be encrypted.